# Is it possible to implement a massive look up table (100 million + keys) in python?

Tags: python

I am going to have a program that generates a 100 million unique keys, and each key has a value associated with it (maximum of 4 digits). I then want to be able to access that data as fast as possible, so that I can look up a key and get its value. Ideally at least a million times a second.

Assuming normal computing power, Is this even possible? Do I just create it as a dictionary or should I start learning about databases and such?

Anything that points me in the right direction would be a huge help.

Comment: this seems better suited to a simple database. .. but probably possible (with ~ enough ~ ram)

Comment: What stops you from simply trying out simplest approach to see it works for you?

Comment: Maybe a job for a [Berkeley DB](http://docs.python.org/2/library/bsddb.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick math says you can't do it in-memory in Python on a 32-bit system.  10<sup>8</sup> keys will give you only 30 bytes per key if you have 3 GB of address space available.

On a 64-bit system, the overhead for a key and value will take up at least:

- 8 bytes per pointer in the bucket, and one pointer each for the key and value,
- Probably 28 bytes for each key and value (`sys.getsizeof(0)` gives 28 on my 64-bit system)

So our estimate is that it will take at least 7.2 GB of memory.  You *can* do it, but you may get unacceptable performance.  I recommend using something simple like Kyoto Cabinet.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have enough ram to test 100m, but I generated a 50 million item dict() and ran 1 million lookups in .25 seconds on my notebook. You are in the ballpark.

```
import time

d = dict((k,k) for k in range(5*10**7))
time.sleep(2) # let system settle
print('start')
start = time.time()
for i in range(10**6):
    x = d[i]
print(time.time() - start)
```

gave me

```
start
.25
```